# Binding to custom XML part not working on deployment

Tags: c#, data-binding, ms-word, vsto, clickonce

I wish to bind Word content controls to Custom XML parts in a VSTO Document customisation. I have followed [Walkthrough: Bind Content Controls to custom XML parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-binding-content-controls-to-custom-xml-parts) on Visual Studio Docs precisely. This works perfectly in test with the following results after pressing start.

[image]

But after publishing the document level customisation using ClickOnce and (apparently successfully) opening the document (ie without any error messages appearing) in the deployed environment, the drop down list is not populated.

[image]

What additional / specific deployment related setting(s) or procedures are required for this to work once published and installed?

The publishing steps I have taken are:
1. Sign the `ClickOnce` manifests using my code signing certificate from Digicert
2. Click `check every time the customisation runs` under `Publish/Updates`
3. Press `Publish`
4. Zip the `publish` directory and upload to MyDrive on Google
5. Download the zipped `publish` file to the deployment environment
6. Unzip the `publish` file and copy it to the installation directory
7. Run the `setup` kit.
8. Copy `employeeControls.docx` from the installation directory to the target directory (identified as a trusted location)
9. Double click on `employeeControls.docx` to start it up.

EDIT I have added logging and a try catch clause around the code and have proven that each of the lines of code are running without generating any exception both in test and after deployment. But while the Binding statements given in the walkthrough:

```
string xPathTitle = "ns:employees/ns:employee/ns:title";
this.dropDownListContentControl1.XMLMapping.SetMapping(xPathTitle, prefix, employeeXMLPart);
```

result in the drop down list control being successfully populated in test, it is not populated after deployment.

EDIT I have investigated whether Protected View settings might be a cause, but have also established that disabling Protected View in the Trust Centre makes no difference.

Comment: The link you provide to the steps you followed is not valid. Please check and update it. Also, do you have logging in the code that runs on start up so that you can see whether everything is being executed? And is your code in try-catch blocks? If it's not, and Word is generating any errors, it's likely they're not being passed up to VSTO...

Comment: There's a Help tab in your first screenshot that isn't in the second. Is that your tab?  If so, your add-in might not actually be running.

Comment: No, I have published the code exactly as given in the article without any adjustments which has no additional logging or try catch. I will add those in to get more info.

Comment: It is a document level customisation rather than an add in and the code is definitely running because its the existing binding code that effectively adds the data eg Karina Leal and April 1 1999 into the controls. I suspect there is an error as Cindy has suggested that is not getting caught and displayed in the deployed environment that is not occurring in test.

Comment: Don't forget to "ping" people you're answering in comments @January59.

Comment: I have added logging and try-catch block but unfortunately with no change in the result. I have edited the question to cover those points as well. @CindyMeister